# PHP Change string to datetime format on sql

Tags: php, datetime, datetimepicker

How can I change this string format "17 August 2014 - 23:30" to a mysql datetime format on PHP

Comment: Simply check the timestamp

Comment: `strtotime` and `date`.

Comment: see my answer... try and update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works in PHP 5.2 and above

```
  <?php
  $time=new DateTime("17 August 2014  23:30");
  echo $time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  ?>
```

if your string has hyphen use the below code

```
   $value = "17 August 2014 - 23:30";
   $value = str_replace('-',' ', $value);
   $time=new DateTime($value);
    echo $time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

$d1=new DateTime("17 August 2014 - 23:30");

check this for more information: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php